# Is Analysis I by Terence Tao incomplete?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am trying self-study real analysis using [Analysis I by Terence Tao](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9380250649) .
I came across some of the following:

Chapter 1: Introduction, page 8:

> Limit interchange is always untrustworthy? (See Proposition $11.15 .3$
> for an answer.

But there is no `Proposition 11.15.3`. Chapter 11 has only 10 sections.

Another example from chapter1 page 10:

> Since $1 \neq 0,$ we thus seem to have shown that interchange of
> derivatives is untrustworthy. But are there any other circumstances in
> which the interchange of derivatives is legitimate? (See Theorem
> $11.37 .4$ and Exercise $11.37 .1$  for some answers.)

Again I could find neither `Theorem 11.37.4` nor `Exercise 11.37.1`.

Am I missing something or is there is some mistake in the book?

Comment: Tangentiially, the screen capture says 11.15.3 not 11.15.13, but that's likely not the relevant point. Still it could cause confusion.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: that can be typos, as Terence Tao often do

Comment: By the way, for your book-recommendation tag, I really recommend Introduction to real analysis by Bartle for a introduction to real analysis, and Real analysis by Royden and Principles of mathematical analysis by Rudin for further study of real analysis.

Comment: Could these be references to his Book 2?

Comment: I guess so; this book has part 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nicholas Roberts pointed out, those are (wrong) references to parts of the second volume.

**Example 1.2.8** is mentioned in *Analysis II*, **Example 3.2.5**.
Proposition which answers the question on the interchangeability of limits is indeed **Proposition 3.3.3** in the second volume.

On the other hand, the question of **Example 1.2.11** about interchangeability of partial derivatives is answered in **Theorem 6.5.4** (Clairaut's theorem) and *Exercise 6.5.1* again in *Analysis II*.